# Inverse of the sum of identiy matrix and a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Is there a simple way to solve $(I + A) X = B$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, and $A$ is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: So $A,B$ are given and you want to find $X$ in terms of them. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Since you don't specify any properties of $A$ other than that it's symmetric, this is essentially the same as asking whether there's a simple way to solve $CX=B$, where $C$ is symmetric (then choose $C=I+A$). There isn't a simple way, but it seems to be possible to make use of the symmetry; see e.g. http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/697664.pdf.

Comment: what if  $A^{-1}$ is known? Would that have a solution?

Comment: I don't think that on its own would help. What would help would be if either $A$ is small, or $A^{-1}$ is known and small; then you could use a series expansion. These expansions would converge if the magnitudes of all eigenvalues of $A$ are less than $1$ (when using $A$) or all are greater than $1$ (when using $A^{-1}$).